# Сортирование list с пользовательским типом данных c++

Tags: c++

Доброе утро, не получается отсортировать  по убыванию.

```
class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
    Student(string Name, int Age) { name = Name; age = Age; }
    Student() {};
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Student &point);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Student &point)
{
    out << point.name << ", " << to_string(point.age) << endl;
    return out;
}


void sort(vector<Student>  &v) {
    int k = v.size();
    Student temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
            if (v[i] < v[j])
            {
                temp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = temp;
            }
}



bool operator < (Student &a, Student &b)
{
    Student temp; Student temp2;
    if (temp.age < temp2.age) return temp.age;
    else return temp2.age;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    vector<Student> list;
    list.emplace_back("Иванов", 45);
    list.emplace_back("Петров", 30);
    list.emplace_back("Сидоров", 55);
    list.emplace_back("Коробков", 45);
    list.emplace_back("Ермолаев", 30);
    list.emplace_back("Витушкин", 55);
    sort(list);


    for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i;
    }
```

Ошибка : error C2678: бинарный "<": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "_Ty" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует);

Comment: Создай `operator<()` для своего класса. Ты там накосячил с типами.

Comment: я его создал, может что то не правильно в нём?

Comment: я пока вижу только логическую ошибку. У тебя `operator<` возвращает `bool`, а ты возвращаешь `int`

Comment: Вы создали свободную функцию, передаете в нее объекты по ссылке, но зачем-то используете временные объекты. Причем возвращаете int, хотя в заголовке функции указано bool.

Comment: Поскольку тут уже наговорили по сути, скажу не по сути вопроса - имейте совесть, не называйте переменную типа `vector` - ``list`. Как и переменную типа `list` - `vector`. Очень путает... Особенно если вы в заголовке спрашиваете, как сортировать `list`, а в вопросе - `vector` - это просто сбивает с толку!

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: не используйте `using namespace std`. Вот вы используете функцию `sort` - а какую вы юзаете: из стандартной библиотеки или свою самописную? Ладно еще в вашем случае сигнатуры не сходятся, но это ОЧЕНЬ плохая практика.

Во-вторых, так как вы используете все-таки свою не шаблонную функцию `sort`, то возникает вопрос: а откуда она знает как сравнивать ваши объекты? Вы сказали что создали `operator<`, но, позвольте, а откуда ваша функция о нем знает? У вас нету объявления этой функции, а определение ниже функции sort. Добавте объявление перед `sort` или вынесите туда определение

Comment: Да, это мой косяк, не так прочитал

Answer (score 0):

- Любой конструктор  класса должен инициализировать свои не
  инициализированные члены, в том числе и конструктор по умолчанию
  вашего класса. Например так:

  ```
  Student::Student() :name(" "), age(0) {};
  ```
- Оператор сравнения выполняет какие то  действия, не связанные с передаваемыми объектами, которые нужно сравнивать, и не
  принимает ни константные объекты,ни временные объекты. А также  возвращает не результат сравнения, а  информацию об отличии от нуля члена какого то объекта, в данном случаи возраста какого то постороннего студента, который к тому же не существует. Оператор нужно  переписать:

  ```
  bool operator < (const Student& a, const Student& b)
  {  return a.age < b.age;   }
  ```
- Только после определения этого оператора можно написать вашу функцию
  сортировки, дабы она знала как сравнивать. Но в условии цикла
  сравнения нужно определиться. Если вы хотите сортировать вектор от
  меньшего к  большему, то  менять местами тогда, когда сравниваемый
  элемент меньше, а не когда меньше тот, с чем сравниваете:

  ```
  void sort(vector<Student>& v) {
     int k = v.size();
     Student temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
         for (int j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
           if (v[j] < v[i]) //исправлено
           {
               temp = v[i];
               v[i] = v[j];
               v[j] = temp;
           }
   }
  ```

Но лучше использовать стандартный алгоритм сортировки:

```
void sort(vector<Student>& v) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```